# Vue You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm using `Vue.js 3.0.11` with Typescript.

Like in the title, How to fix this errors ?
Is this because I'm using class type function or because of something else ?
I tried to change the `target` to `es5`, still got same error ..

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                     2:52:06 PM

 error  in ./src/library/UniswapV2PancakeswapV2Router.ts

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:8)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/.pnpm/cache-loader@4.1.0_webpack@4.46.0/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/.pnpm/ts-loader@6.2.2_typescript@4.3.2/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/.pnpm/eslint-loader@2.2.1_eslint@7.27.0+webpack@4.46.0/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import fromExponential from "from-exponential";
| export default class UniswapV2PancakeswapV2Router {
>     web3;
|     routerAddress;
|     contractInstance;

 @ ./src/library/RouterInstance.ts 1:0-82 6:23-51
 @ ./node_modules/.pnpm/cache-loader@4.1.0_webpack@4.46.0/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/.pnpm/ts-loader@6.2.2_typescript@4.3.2/node_modules/ts-loader??ref--13-1!./node_modules/.pnpm/cache-loader@4.1.0_webpack@4.46.0/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/.pnpm/vue-loader@16.2.0/node_modules/vue-loader/dist??ref--0-1!./src/views/Bot.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/views/Bot.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/views/Bot.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./node_modules/.pnpm/webpack-dev-server@3.11.2_webpack@4.46.0/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.104:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
```

Here the `UniswapV2PancakeswapV2Router.ts`

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import BigNumber from "bignumber.js";
import { Contract } from "web3-eth-contract";
import uniswapRouterV2abi from "@/plugins/uniswapRouterV2abi";
import fromExponential from "from-exponential";
import { Router } from "@/interfaces/router";

export default class UniswapV2PancakeswapV2Router implements Router {
  web3!: Web3;
  routerAddress!: string;
  contractInstance!: Contract;
  constructor(web3: Web3, routerAddress: string) {
    this.web3 = web3 as Web3;
    this.routerAddress = routerAddress;
    this.contractInstance = new this.web3.eth.Contract(
      uniswapRouterV2abi,
      this.routerAddress
    );
  }

  async getOutputAmount(
    inputAmount: BigNumber,
    contractAddressInput: string,
    contractAddressOutput: string
  ): Promise<BigNumber> {
    const path = [contractAddressInput, contractAddressOutput];
    const amountOut = await this.contractInstance.methods
      .getAmountsOut(fromExponential(inputAmount.toString()), path)
      .call();
    return new BigNumber(amountOut[1]);
  }
}
```

this is my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost",
      "ES2016.Array.Include",
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```